# multibootISOs missing items?

Tags: linux, boot

it seems that many items are missing from MultiBootIsos...exe operating-systems list.
i remember seeing there clonezilla, PMagic, maybe more, but they're gone now, for all versions of the program i have:

```
MultiBootISOs-2.1.4.4.exe
MultiBootISOs-2.1.4.2.exe
MultiBootISOs-2.1.3.9.exe
```

why they are missing?

how can i "revive" missing items in this programs?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ha!

i had to first use "MultiBootISOs-2.1.3.9.exe".
apparently, it formatted the USB drive in such a way, that enabled me to install clonezilla.

but not so simple.

first i installed DSL

then i found clonezilla (along with other options) in the list.

what an awkward thing